# Deployed Editor Google Sheets Add-on not Showing up for Domain Members

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I created a google app script to execute some code and format a file in a specific way. I tested the app and it worked perfectly. However, after deploying it to our G suite, it is not appearing in the menu as it should.

When I run the script as an installed add-on, it functions as it should. I installed and deployed the latest version and deployed it as a marketplace app and installed it to our entire domain. However, when I create a new sheet to test if the add-on is installed, the add-on does not appear in the menu as it is programmed to do.

```
function onOpen(e) {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu() // Or DocumentApp.
   .addItem('Format Spreadsheet', 'formatFiles')
   .addToUi();
}
```

Expected results are that each user that has the app installed on their account has a drop down menu in google sheets that lets me select "format spreadsheet". However, nothing is there and the javascript console shows that it is not trying to load.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but it appears that there are two sets of "rules" for custom menus for GSuite. The first [Custom Menus in G Suite](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) seems to apply to scripts; the second [Custom menus for editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/menus) appears to apply to add-ons. The difference appears to be as subtle as using, say, `.addItem` versus `menu.addItem`. You've used the former, and it's not working; so it might be worth looking at the latter.